# Problema con instalar PDO

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

Resulta que tengo este codigo:

```
<?php
    $conexion= new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Mercado","BASEDEDATOS"," ");

    if($conexion){
        echo "Conexion exitosa";
    }else{
        echo"Esta mal la conexion";
    }
?>
```

Al ejecutarlo me sale este error en la pagina:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Pagina\conexion.php:4 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Pagina\conexion.php(4):
>   PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=l...', 'ADMIN', ' ') #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pagina\conexion.php on line 4

Investigue y dicen que tengo que quitar el punto y coma de la extencion pero ya esta quitado y sigue sin funcionar no se que mas pueda ser:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

He visto que otros tienen php y la extencion .dll agregados en las extensiones no se si se deba a eso y de ser asi como lo resuelvo??

Tengo php 7.4.1 eso dice en el phpinfo.

Comment: No sabes lo dificil que es tratar de ver la imagen del error y lo otro desde un celular :(

Comment: Sonará obvio pero... reiniciaste el servidor?

Comment: si ya lo hice pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: ¿puedes por favor agregar texto en vez de imágenes? no se si las revisaste siquiera, pero apenas se nota lo que dicen, tienen una pésima resolución.

Comment: Listo ya esta editado espero les pueda ayudar

Comment: @Victor A¿Lo conseguiste solucionar ?